# Is there a tool for web based system administration?

Tags: server, software-recommendation

What web based system admin tools are there for Ubuntu? Basically I want to setup a headless server at home and want to make it easy for my family to change some settings. I'm familiar with Webmin but want to see what other options are available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

eBox (now zentyal)

```
sudo apt-get install zentyal
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/ebox.html

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/eBox

Note that Webmin is not supported as it's not compatible with Ubuntu package management:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebMin

Answer (score 7):

**[Ajenti](http://ajenti.org/)** is easy to install, easy to use and has powerful tools.

Comment: Note, that Ajenti is single-server only: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels

Comment: ajenti was a buggy experience for me on a default install of ubuntu 14.04 LTS. had to move on

Answer (score 6):

You can limit what they can access with Webmin.  For others looking at this question, check out webmin.

http://www.webmin.com/

Search for "webmin ubuntu" for instructions on installing because it is not a simple apt-get.

Answer (score 4):

## [Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.org)

eBox changed its name to Zentyal recently. They will be coming out with a version 3 soon. It has been under quite a lot of development, and is one of the best administration systems in the market. (Its still free as well).

[Blog post](http://www.zentyal.org/archives/2010/08/19/507-ebox-platform-changes-name-to-zentyal/) detailing the name change.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want on your server [TurnKey](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/) may be worth looking at. They have different appliances based on Ubuntu 8.04 using Webmin as admin frontend.