# Remote administration of a server?

Tags: server, email, administration, ftp, webserver

I'm going to install a ubuntu server to provide email, ftp and maybe webserver services too.
I dont want to install a gui for the server, but I'd like to administrate it remotely.
I was thinking in web administration or something else, is there a good package to make these tasks??

Regards,
Victor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ubuntu Server Team recommend this 2 option:

1.- OpenSSH Server

2.- eBox is a web framework used to manage server application configuration. The modular design of eBox allows you to pick and choose which services you want to configure using eBox.

see details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/remote-administration.html)

3.- in ubuntu server 10.10 ebox was changed with Puppet is a cross platform framework enabling system administrators to perform common tasks using code. The code can do a variety of tasks from installing new software, to checking file permissions, or updating user accounts. Puppet is great not only during the initial installation of a system, but also throughout the system's entire life cycle. In most circumstances puppet will be used in a client/server configuration. more details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/remote-administration.html)

4.- in ubuntu server 12.04 the team introduce Zentyal is a Linux small business server, that can be configured as a Gateway, Infrastructure Manager, Unified Threat Manager, Office Server, Unified Communication Server or a combination of them. Zentyal consists of a serie of packages (usually one for each module) that provide a web interface to configure the different servers or services. The configuration is stored on a key-value Redis database but users, groups and domains related configuration is on OpenLDAP. more details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/zentyal.html)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/6530/78663). eBox apparently has been superseded by [Zentyal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zentyal).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you're looking for [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/). You can administrate the complete system with this Web-Interface.

Answer (score 2):

ispconfig is another good option to control those activities remotely