# How to use software installed on another computer?

Tags: networking, server, latex, lan

I am interested in introducing LaTeX to some students. They have access to computers (most of them have Ubuntu installed) but can't install the software due to lack of administrator privileges. They all are on a LAN, though.

Is it possible to install LaTeX in one computer and put in the same LAN making a server kind of thing, and they can access the computer through a web interface where they can upload the file and compile it in the server and download required files afterwards, pretty much the way many websites do it?

Can we extend the possibility to a list of other software as well?

PS: They have limited internet access.

Update/Edit: As I mentioned, they will not be able to install anything on their machines but I can in one under my control.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex could be interesting. Never tried to install it locally, though.

Comment: @Rmano That's in interesting alternative. I learn something new everyday.

Comment: @Wings Your recent edit asks a second question that has already been answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41106/managing-an-ubuntu-server) In tn order to avoid having this question flagged as either a duplicate or too broad, I'm rolling it back to the previous version.

Answer (score 3):

As I recall [Edubuntu](https://www.edubuntu.org/) is designed with this functionality in mind and includes the [Linux Terminal Server Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Terminal_Server_Project) which appears to be what you are after. I personally don't have much in the way of hands on experience with this, but here's some pertinent info.

> The principal design goals of Edubuntu are centralized management of
>   configuration, users and processes, together with facilities for
>   working collaboratively in a classroom setting. Equally important is
>   the gathering together of the best available free software and digital
>   materials for education.

.

> Linux Terminal Server Project (LTSP) is a free and open source
>   terminal server for Linux that allows many people to simultaneously
>   use the same computer. Applications run on the server with a terminal
>   known as a thin client (also known as an X terminal) handling input
>   and output

There is a great deal of relevant documentation available [here.](https://www.edubuntu.org/documentation)

The Edubuntu DVD is built from the exact same repositories as the Ubuntu discs and other official derivatives so it's not necessary to change flavors if you have a preinstalled flavor of Ubuntu you can simply add to an existing Ubuntu system whatever missing pieces you require.

As an example, the following educational bundles are available in the repositories

```
ubuntu-edu-preschool - Preschool educational application bundle
ubuntu-edu-primary - Primary ( ages 6-12) educational application bundle
ubuntu-edu-secondary - Secondary ( ages 13-18) educational application bundle
ubuntu-edu-tertiary - Tertiary ( university level ) educational application bundle
```

You can also install all Edubuntu packages, including artwork by installing the [edubuntu-desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=edubuntu-desktop&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package.

It doesn't appear that the [texlive](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=texlive&searchon=names) or [texstudio](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texstudio) packages are contained in any of these educational bundles but you can install them separately as needed.

Note that installation of any of these packages requires that you first [enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

That said, **If the content you want to share is on the Edubuntu Live CD**, it might be simpler and easier to simply use This:
[image: LTSP Live]

Edubuntu can be downloaded [here](https://www.edubuntu.org/download)

Edit: Preventing users from installing anything on their systems will take a bit of work on your part. You will have to somehow insure that the users can't boot via live media (USB/Optical Disk). This can typically be accomplished by Setting the boot order to boot from the hard disk only and then password protecting the BIOS. If you've managed to do this, simply not providing them with the administrative password (and not allowing them to see you enter it) should do the trick. The users can still find ways to bypass this [for example if they know the administrative accounts user name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edubuntu

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Terminal_Server_Project

https://www.edubuntu.org/about

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289458/download-and-installation-of-latex-for-linux-ubuntu

[Is there a way to block installations of programs on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346151/is-there-a-way-to-block-installations-of-programs-on-ubuntu)

My rusty memory ;-)

Comment: Sorry, for late response. Do I need Edubuntu on each students' system or just in mine? Also, .. .. I want to point out that I don't want the students to install a software or change the OS for some reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @Wings edited answer.. Edubuntu is as I recall designed around a Client/Server environment so, no the students shouldn't be able to affect your installation on a single machine that they all access via the Linux Terminal Server Project

Comment: I'm not clear with the words: "... no the students shouldn't be able to affect your installation on a single machine that they all access via the Linux Terminal Server Project."

Comment: Ya, I went to do some reading. And, being a newbie, I could guess that Its the LTSP that makes the difference. Still have doubts about ur edit: it says it works with LIve CD.

Comment: If the app you want to share is on the Live CD you can go that route, if not, That shortcut is not the choice for you. Sorry if I was unclear, updated answer...