# How to install webmin?

Tags: webmin

How do I install webmin on Ubuntu 12.04?

Note: I am using the desktop edition, not Ubuntu Server.

Comment: As tomas-w mentioned, webmin is no longer supported officially by Ubuntu.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/6529/is-there-a-tool-for-web-based-system-administration/6530#6530 for alternatives, including zentyal (formerly ebox).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Installation

Open up Terminal and run the following commands, entering your password when prompted. 
Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each command. 
Accept any prompts you may receive.

```
echo "deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib deb" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
cd /tmp; wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc; sudo apt-key add jcameron-key.asc; cd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install webmin
```

That's it! Webmin should now be up and running.

### Usage

#### By IP Address

To find your IP address, run the following command in Terminal:

```
ifconfig | grep eth -A 5 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print "IP Address: "$1}'
```

Browse to that IP address using your favorite web browser, appending `:10000` to the end of the address. For example:

```
192.168.1.10:10000
```

***Note:** `10000` is the default port where Webmin resides, and you must specify it to access Webmin's control panel. If you don't, you'll be accessing the built-in web server's home page, **not** Webmin.*

#### By Hostname

You may also browse to Webmin using your Ubuntu machine's hostname. 
To find your hostname, run the following command in Terminal:

```
hostname
```

***Note:** Again, don't forget to append `:10000` to the hostname in the web browser.*

Comment: The second URL is missing the "deb" in front of it

Comment: webmin is not officially supported anymore by Ubuntu.  As far as I can tell, the apt-get install will fail as a result because webmin was removed from the repositories.  It was replaced with 'ebox'.

Comment: The package click through doesn't work because the package is from a ppa. I'll roll it back.