# can't access SAMBA shares on UBUNTU-server from other computers

Tags: networking, server, samba

Installed UBUNTU-server 12.04 and configured /etc/samba/smb.conf as:

```
 #======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
workgroup = HEMMA 
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
security = user
wins support = yes
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
encrypt passwords = no
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
############ Misc ############
usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================
[printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = no
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = no

[Bilder original]
comment = Original bilder
path = /mnt/bilder/org
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = no
create mask = 0755
[Bilder publika]
comment = Bilder för allmän visning
path = /mnt/bilder/public
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = yes
[Musik]
comment = Musik
path = /mnt/music/public
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = yes
```

I have a network setup around a 4G router "HUAWEI B593" where some computers are connected by WIFI and others by LAN.

The server is connected by LAN.

On one computer running windows XP I can see the server but are not allowed to acces them.

On another computer on the WIFI-net running win7 I cannot see the server at all but I can ping the server and I can see the smb-protocoll is running when sniffing with wireshark.

I don't primarily want to use passwords, computers on the lan and wifi should be able to connect without any login-procedure.

I'm sure my config is not sufficient but have hard to understand how I should do. Theres a lot of descriptions on the net but most is old and none have been of any help.

I'm also confused by the fact that I can not se the sever on my win7-machine even though it communicates with the samba-server.

Would be very happy if anyone could spread some light over this mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to ping the Ubuntu server, and still not able to map network drive from Windows follow this:

Just disconnect the LAN cable , connect to WLAN. Now type-in the IP-address/username(eg: //192.134.23.23/joe) into the explorer.
Mostly you should be able to connect. If yes, just copy the path to network map the drive.
Hope this works.
The problem should be with the server hostname mapping with ip-address.

Answer (score 0):

ideally, if you are not an IT geek, use **Webmin** ([How to install webmin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145165/how-to-install-webmin)), installable as a deb package. All configurations you can do in web interface, more understandable for anyone. 
You can try their demo: http://www.webmin.com/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

`Map to guest` is set to `Bad User` and some of your shares are allowed for the guest user so this is sufficient for samba to open unauthorised access to those shares, there should be no problem. Another question is file-system permissions on those folders. Please check whether `nouser` (defined by `guest account` parameter) is allowed to access your shares.

Answer (score 0):

you did change in `smb.conf`

```
workgroup = HEMMA
```

your window pc should be in `HEMMA` workgroup . by default windows workgroup is `WORKGROUP`. so , you have to change it to `HEMMA` 
otherwise change in `smb.conf`

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP
```

and make sure you have following line in `smb.conf` file

```
wins support = yes
local master = yes
preferred master = yes
```

after changing don't forget to restart samba service

```
sudo service smbd restart
```