# Using Webmin on Ubuntu server for Samba

Tags: server, samba, webmin

I want to use Webmin for managing user/groups and permissions on a SAMBA server.
Is it possible to use Webmin exclusively to do this?
Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install webmin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145165/how-to-install-webmin)

Comment: @ArturMeinild sorry My question is notcorrect. I mean, can I do thai with webmin is webmin enought? I want to be sure and I need to ask people who use webmin

Comment: Edit the question do not make edits to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is "it depends".

If you want to use the most common functionality and options, then yes - Webmin should provide the necessary options.

However, there might be some advanced features and edge cases that's not covered by Webmin, but I'm not aware of what these might be exactly.

The [Samba module wiki page](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Samba_Windows_File_Sharing) explains what settings you can expect to find in Webmin Samba module.