# Resources for learning about Ubuntu server administration

Tags: server, administration

I'm looking for recommendations (either book or online course) for learning about Ubuntu server administration in the context of web application hosting. In particular, it should cover the following topics:

- How to secure the server against potential threats
- Which log files to monitor, what information to look at
- How to diagnose performance issues (speed/memory/network)
- How to handle software/package updates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a tool for web based system administration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6529/is-there-a-tool-for-web-based-system-administration)

Comment: @24601 no sorry, I'm looking for educational resources, not tools.

Comment: Secure against potential threats: The [Ubuntu Security Podcast](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/) published a four-episode series on precisely this topic, starting at episode 151.

Comment: It's not too broad to ask for an Ubuntu Server book. It seems to me like the illogical assumption of some reviewers of this question is that a simple request for an Ubuntu Server book is too broad in case the book has too many pages or the podcast has too many episodes, but it actually makes no difference to Ask Ubuntu whether the book is long or short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu Server Guide](https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/f954307f-ubuntu-server-guide.pdf) is a free book which includes information on using Ubuntu Server for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and later. The same book is also available in older editions for Ubuntu Server 16.04 and Ubuntu Server 18.04, but an edition of Ubuntu Server Guide for Ubuntu Server 22.04 has not been released yet.